# How to kill all activity when pressing back key at android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

There are two activities, Start Activity is composed VideoView and Main Activity(listview) overlays on VideoView. Because I don't know how to overlay Listview transparently on videoview at one activity. That's why I used two activity.

```
StartActivity(videoView) -> MainActivity(Listview)
```

The problem is that when I finish this app using back key, only ListView is killed. So I have to press back key again for killing videoView. I have searched all info, but I can't find out.

Comment: when your press back your activity is killed

Comment: use finish()............

Comment: try making your videoView Activity a oneshot activity using android:noHistory="true" in manifest

Answer (score 0):

when you go to Listview from videoview, at that time use finish() with intent. just like below

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity_Listview.this,
                    Activity_videoview.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to use ("to overlay the listview") is a **[fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)**.

Since your app will only use 1 activity it will exit immediately when the back button is pressed. This would be the correct way to do the thing you described instead of trying to kill 2 activities with 1 back-key press.

Answer (score 0):

When launching MainActivity(Listview) you could use startActivityForResult (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int) ) and in the setResult method you can add some information which then to trigger the finishing of StartActivity(videoView).
Please note that these are only tricks. The correct implementation would be to use Fragments (as user3249477 suggested).